# How do I remove the pattern lock?

Tags: pattern-lock

I have my brothers old HTC & was playing with the Location & Security settings. I added the pattern lock to my phone, but it's now just an extra thing to get through before being able to use my phone. How can I remove this? I'm rather clueless with the terminology too & don't grasp the concept of APN's & VPN's or know what a corporate administrator is.

Comment: When the "none" option in key lock settings is greyed out: Fail the pattern on purpose multiple times, wait out the time-lock, use your PIN to log in and the pattern lock will have been removed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In your phone go to the settings options and check for Security settings and find key lock settings.

1. You will have Some options like PIN, Pattern, None.
2. Pin is for the phone will ask you for a 4-digit number to unlock
   your phone.
3. Pattern is for the phone will ask you to draw the pattern for the
   phone to unlock the phone. The  pattern should be the same as the pattern you
   had set.
4. Choose none for the phone will not ask for any pattern or pin to
   unlock your phone.In this way you will be free of any hassles to unlock your phone.

Comment: @bouncy72 did the above work for you

Answer (score 0):

Every Phone Have option to remove the pattern lock.

Go to the

> 1.Setting
>
> 2.Security
>
> 3.Screen lock
>
> 4.click
>
> 5.Option Coming(none, Pattern, PIN, Password).
>
> 6.Choose NONE option.

Then you have remove the pattern lock. 
In android every phone have same process.

Above answer is also correct. I have updated only how to remove pattern lock specifically.